# jq iteration and conditions

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

I have some json that I need to parse using jq. I am trying to extract the 
SecurityGroups>GroupId if any of the SecurityGroups>IpPermissions>IpRanges>CidrIp matches a certain IP.

For instance, searching for 11.11.11.11 should return sg-3jf32kj3j. There is a possibility that multiple SecurityGroups will contain that IP. I need to return every GroupId that does.

Is this even possible with jq alone or will it require bash as well?

I'm finding jq syntax confusing compared to just doing this with something like Python.

```
{
"SecurityGroups": [{
        "OwnerId": "111111111",
        "Description": "default VPC security group",
        "GroupId": "sg-1a1a1a1a1",
        "VpcId": "vpc-1a1a1a1a1",
        "IpPermissionsEgress": [{
            "IpProtocol": "-1",
            "PrefixListIds": [],
            "Ipv6Ranges": [],
            "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
            "IpRanges": [{
                "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }]
        }],
        "GroupName": "default",
        "IpPermissions": [{
            "IpProtocol": "-1",
            "PrefixListIds": [],
            "Ipv6Ranges": [],
            "UserIdGroupPairs": [{
                "GroupId": "sg-5df45d5d5",
                "UserId": "234234234"
            }],
            "IpRanges": []
        }]
    },
    {
        "OwnerId": "22222222222",
        "Description": "EC2 Security Group",
        "Tags": [{
                "Key": "aws:cloudformation:logical-id",
                "Value": "EC2SecurityGroup"
            },
            {
                "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-id",
                "Value": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:111111111:stack/blah-prod-vpc/asdfsdf-j3j3-22j1-39fj-sadfsadf"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "blah-production-EC2"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Owner",
                "Value": "blah@blah.com"
            },
            {
                "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name",
                "Value": "prod-vpc"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Created",
                "Value": "2018-05-21T09:40:55-07:00"
            }
        ],
        "GroupId": "sg-3jf32kj3j",
        "VpcId": "vpc-3kj3f2kj3",
        "IpPermissionsEgress": [{
            "IpProtocol": "-1",
            "PrefixListIds": [],
            "Ipv6Ranges": [],
            "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
            "IpRanges": [{
                "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }]
        }],
        "GroupName": "blah-prod-vpc-EC2SecurityGroup-SJHS78F78SSH",
        "IpPermissions": [{
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "ToPort": 80,
                "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                "IpRanges": [{
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }],
                "FromPort": 80,
                "PrefixListIds": [],
                "Ipv6Ranges": []
            },
            {
                "IpProtocol": "icmp",
                "ToPort": 0,
                "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                "IpRanges": [{
                    "CidrIp": "11.11.11.11/32"
                }],
                "FromPort": 0,
                "PrefixListIds": [],
                "Ipv6Ranges": []
            },
            {
                "IpProtocol": "-1",
                "PrefixListIds": [],
                "Ipv6Ranges": [],
                "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                "IpRanges": [{
                        "CidrIp": "22.22.22.22/16"
                    },
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "33.33.33.33/32"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "ToPort": 22,
                "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                "IpRanges": [{
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }],
                "FromPort": 22,
                "PrefixListIds": [],
                "Ipv6Ranges": [{
                    "CidrIpv6": "::/0"
                }]
            },
            {
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "ToPort": 443,
                "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                "IpRanges": [{
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }],
                "FromPort": 443,
                "PrefixListIds": [],
                "Ipv6Ranges": []
            },
            {
                "IpProtocol": "icmp",
                "ToPort": -1,
                "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                "IpRanges": [{
                        "CidrIp": "44.44.44.44/32"
                    },
                    {
                        "CidrIp": "55.55.55.55/29"
                    }
                ],
                "FromPort": -1,
                "PrefixListIds": [],
                "Ipv6Ranges": []
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following filter meets the stated requirements:

```
.SecurityGroups[]
| select( any(.IpPermissions[].IpRanges[];
              .CidrIp | startswith("11.11.11.11/") ) )
| .GroupId
```

In particular, with your input it yields the required value:

```
"sg-3jf32kj3j"
```

You might want to consider more sophisticated pattern-matching, perhaps using:

```
test("^11.11.11.11($|/)")
```

If you want the quotation marks to be dropped, consider using the -r command-line option of jq.

### Using ..

Here's another solution, but please note that it has completely different semantics:

```
..
| select( .. |  test("^11.11.11.11($|/)")? )
| .GroupId? // empty
```

Answer (score 0):

may I offer you an alternative solution to your ask? this is how it looks like with the unix utility `jtc` I have developed recently:

```
bash $ cat file.json | jtc -w'<^11.11.11.11\/>R: [-5] [GroupId]' 
"sg-3jf32kj3j"
bash $
```

it will also display all groups where this ip address shows up. If you like it, you can find the utility on github.com or google it up with `jtc` and `json` keywords